# Remastering Iso

Tags: elementary-website

I have downloaded the Elementary OS from https://elementary.io/ and am wanting to remaster it to add additional packages such as LAMP Stack.  I am looking at the tutorial here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallCDCustomization but I do not see a pre seed file?  (step after extracting the .iso to my hard drive)

Am I doing something incorrect here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download uck from the repositories, it's a nice tool to customize iso's.

sudo apt-get install uck

Or you can do it manually.

I used this tutorial once, a bit long but it is great.

https://nathanpfry.com/how-to-customize-an-ubuntu-installation-disc/